# angularJS http GET parameter gets undefined on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, http

I have this chunk of code in my controller.js file

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/getGuestList',
    params: {exhibitorID: 1}
})
```

Basically, it's supposed to get all the guests of a certain exhibitor whose exhibitor ID is 1.

On the server side, I have tried logging `req.body.params` and `req.body.exhibitorID` but both of them are undefined. I'm just getting familiar with angularjs and I don't know what I'm missing.

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which server technology stack you are using. You may also need to edit your post to include code from the server.

Comment: Mr. Vendhan had already provided a working answer. Thank you very much for your feedback. I will consider that next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NodeJS try,

```
req.query.exhibitorID
```

[API DOCS](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query)

Answer (score 0):

params are req.params, they are not in req.body

Comment: yes, i get your point. However, `req.params.exhibitorID` is still undefined. :(

Comment: are you using express? if yes then how your define your routes

Comment: this is how I routed it from my app.js: `app.get('/getGuestList', routes.getGuestList);`

Comment: you are not using name route, that's why you need to use req.query

Comment: I see. so that's the difference. thank you for this! :)